# Is assignment of braced-init-list to an array correct?

Tags: c++, c++11, g++, language-lawyer, standards-compliance

The standard says, under 5.17/9

> A braced-init-list may appear on the right-hand side of
>       - an assignment to a scalar [...]
>       - an assignment defined by a user-defined assignment operator [..]

While in GCC 4.5.1-pre9999, I can compile this (using -std=c++0x, NOT -std=gnu++0x)

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
        int test[] = {1,2,3};
        std::cout << test[0] << test[1] << test[2];
        test = {4,5,6};
        std::cout << test[0] << test[1] << test[2] << std::endl;
}
```

and it prints `123456`. Is GCC correct here?

Comment: Voting to close because this is too localized, it's a bug in now-obsolete compiler version.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like a bug to me. The initialization (`int test = {1,2,3};`) is fine, but as far as I can see, nothing in the standard allows the assignment.

Comment: And if it were allowed, logically so should array assignment be.

Comment: You were right, apparently it was a GCC bug and it was fixed in GCC 4.6: http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=44045#c12